# how to add multiple clients discord.py code

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from keep_alive import keep_alive

client=commands.Bot(command_prefix=':', self_bot=True, help_command=None)

GUILD_ID = 952514037596438588
CHANNEL_ID = 977851845722664980

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    os.system('clear')
    print(f'Logged in as {client.user} ({client.user.id})')
    vc = discord.utils.get(client.get_guild(GUILD_ID).channels, id = CHANNEL_ID)
    await vc.guild.change_voice_state(channel=vc, self_mute=False, self_deaf=False)
    print(f"Successfully joined {vc.name} ({vc.id})")

keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

in this code i can only add one token, one channel id and one server id and i want to multiply this to add other tokens

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: this code is to make a discord account go online and join a voice channel using the account token. in GUILD_ID put the id of the server and in CHANNEL_ID it is the id of the voice channel. however, you can only use one account, and I want to know what I need to add to the code to be able to use multiple accounts.

Comment: Botting any user accounts is against Discord TOS